# Qt C++ Unhandled exceptions stack trace

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, exception, dump

I am trying to figure out a way to get the stack trace of a deployed c++ application in the event of a crash. I have tried a couple of approaches and I think my issue is related to the stack after an exception occurs.

I created a test application in Qt. Here is the code.

```
void miniDumpFunc()
{
    MiniDump dump;
    dump.Create(L"C:\\dmp\\dmp.dmp");
}

void anotherFunc()
{
    miniDumpFunc();
}

LONG WINAPI OurCrashHandler(EXCEPTION_POINTERS * /*ExceptionInfo*/)
{
    miniDumpFunc();

    return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
}

void badFunc()
{
    int *myNull = NULL;
    *myNull = 42;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    ::SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(OurCrashHandler);

    anotherFunc();

    return app.exec();
}
```

If I call anotherFunc() and then look at the stack trace in WinDbg I get the following stack.

[image]

I think there is some in-lining going on here, but it looks about right.

If I call badFunc() however this is what I get.
[image]

The stack trace starts at UnhandledExceptionFilter. It seems like the stack is getting messed up by the exception.

Here is where I got the code to generate the mini dumps. http://blog.aaronballman.com/2011/05/generating-a-minidump/

Comment: If you don't pass along the `EXCEPTION_POINTERS` to `MiniDumpWriteDump`, it has no way of writing a dump starting from the code that raised the SEH exception. Pass those along (use `nullptr` in case you want to write a dump without handling an exception). A word of warning on the implementation you are using: This **will** deadlock at some point. You absolutely, positively do want to call `MiniDumpWriteDump` in its own process.

Comment: The article (and implementation) you linked to is so broken beyond hope of regeneration, that I strongly recommend to write your own (from reliable information, like [DebugInfo.com](http://www.debuginfo.com/articles/effminidumps.html)). The author is completely unaware of what he is doing, or what the API he is using does, for that matter (e.g. `MiniDumpWriteDump` already suspends all threads). Stay clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stack trace you posted for `badFunc` is perfectly fine, and the expected result, given the implementation you are using. [MiniDumpWriteDump](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680360.aspx) runs a stack trace using the current instruction pointer, unless you are passing the SEH exception's [EXCEPTION_POINTERS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679331.aspx) through the [MINIDUMP_EXCEPTION_INFORMATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680366.aspx) structure. Since the unhandled exception filter is installed at the bottom of the exception frames, calling `MiniDumpWriteDump` from there produces the stack trace you observed.

To get a more helpful stack trace, you need to pass the `EXCEPTION_POINTERS` to `MiniDumpWriteDump`.

This is just one of many issues with the [implementation you are using](http://blog.aaronballman.com/2011/05/generating-a-minidump/). There are more:

- The author seems to be well aware, that they can pass `nullptr` for the `ExceptionParam` parameter, but then moves on to decide to **always** pass `nullptr`. The interface should really provide two overloads: One that takes an `EXCEPTION_POINTERS` argument, and one without. This allows the functionality to be called from anywhere, but also retains the stack trace, when called from an unhandled exception filter (the latter is by far the most common use case).
- The author raises an *"interesting question: what should be done with other threads in the application?"* As it stands, `MiniDumpWriteDump` already suspends **all** threads in the process before moving forward. You don't even have a choice there. The entire implementation to suspend threads (including the filter to exclude the helper thread) is superfluous. It needs to go.
- The author fails to address a real issue (both of the vanilla `MiniDumpWriteDump`, as well as their own thread suspending implementation): Threads get suspended at arbitrary points. If any of these threads hold any locks (like the global heap allocation mutex), you are in for an instant dead lock. After all, `MiniDumpWriteDump` will want to allocate memory from the process heap as well. The solution here is more involved: The call to `MiniDumpWriteDump` must be performed in its own process, with appropriate IPC in place.

Either of the above is a fairly substantial bug, and needs to be addressed. As [published](http://code.aaronballman.com/minidumper/), the code is both useless as well as dangerous. If you feel like implementing your own solution in the meantime, have a look at the following resources for reliable information:

- [Effective Minidumps - Part 1](http://www.debuginfo.com/articles/effminidumps.html)
- [Effective Minidumps - Part 2](http://www.debuginfo.com/articles/effminidumps2.html)

Comment: Can you post an official source. While most of it might make sense, MSFT's own docs are somewhat unclear.  For instance, the "Remarks" section of "MiniDumpWriteDump()" states that calling it should be done from a separate process, but emphasizes it's more important for a crashed app. They then seem to tacitly approve of calling it from an app that hasn't crashed by stating "... you can call the function from a new worker thread and filter this worker thread from the dump." They can't have it both ways though. It's either safe to call from an "uncrashed" app or not ...

Comment: ... If it *may* be unsafe from an "uncrashed" app however, how can a developer really know. They can't since such such an assumption would be extremely brittle. Calling it from a separate app therefore seems the only way to go (whether the target app has crashed or not), but again, MSFT's own docs confuse the situation (and their own quote about filtering the worker thread renders your statement about suspending threads "superfluous", not quite the whole story, which I say respectfully - the very point is even irrelevant if a separate process is in fact the only reliable thing to do)

Comment: @Larry: I have nothing more official to offer, and wish the MSDN were clearer on the topic. What I do have to offer is personal experience. I did debug a deadlock caused by calling `MiniDumpWriteDump` from the faulting program. It was caused by one of the suspended threads holding the process heap lock, when `MiniDumpWriteDump` itself tried to allocate memory. This can happen at any time, so it is *never* safe to call `MiniDumpWriteDump` from within a program.

Comment: @Larry: Thinking about it, though, there *might* be a scenario, where `MiniDumpWriteDump` is indeed safe to call from the faulting application: If the application is statically linked against the CRT. In this setup, the application uses a different heap from the system call (I believe, anyway). That could be there reason, why the MSDN is this opaque on the topic. Even then, I wouldn't recommend doing it. There was another deadlock, which I didn't analyze to the point of certainty, so there is more potential for failure. If you want to play it safe, I'd strongly recommend to decouple the call.

Comment: @Inspectable: I agree. I've had my own code running for years but I only use it in a crash scenario. A separate ".exe" is definitely the way go here, but I'm now investigating something related to a "non-crash" scenario. In any case, one final question. In reference to your deadlock being caused because "... one of the suspended threads [was] holding the process heap lock ...", was that you who explicitly suspended the thread (presumably just to test things), or because you believe "MiniDumpWriteDump()" itself had suspended it (probably the latter, but if so, how did you confirm this).

Comment: @Larry: The thread that was in the middle of allocating heap memory was suspended by `MiniDumpWriteDump`. There was no code explicitly suspending threads in the application, and *all* threads were showing up as suspended in the dump file I took. It's also important to note, that it doesn't matter, whether the application is in a well defined or in an unexpected state. Case in point being an application that was perfectly stable, with one thread generating non-fatal floating point exceptions at a high rate. If you find it helpful I'll see if I can craft a proof-of-concept illustrating this.

Comment: @Inspectable: Ok, appreciate the info. I just wanted to make sure it was in fact "MiniDumpWriteDump()" suspending the threads and not you. The info you provided was very valuable to my investigation. Don't worry about a proof-of-concept, I can take things from here (thanks though). BTW, if you (or others) weren't aware of it (MSFT doesn't widely publish it the last time I looked), you can open a minidump directly in Visual Studio itself. It lets you effectively break at a crash line as if the crash occurred during a debug session (with full stack info, etc.). Let me know if you want details.

Comment: @Larry: In my experience, not all dump files generated through `MiniDumpWriteDump` could in fact be opened in Visual Studio. I forgot, which pieces of information are required to do so. WinDbg, on the other hand, did open any dump. And it's a better tool to diagnose deadlocks, too. There's just no equivalent to its `!locks` command in Visual Studio, and once you need to peek inside the `ERESOURCE` structure to determine contention count or the lock's owner, Visual Studio doesn't have anything to offer. It's a fine debugger, just not for everything you would ever need to debug.

Comment: @Inspectable: Well that certainly isn't surprising since WinDbg is a dedicated debugger (unlike VS). For many (probably even most) garden-variety crashes though, VS does the job just fine. The advantage is that the environment is more familiar to most developers. Its ability to simulate a break at the crash line works very well (so most developers will already be familiar with how to check the stack, local variables, etc.). In any case, I'm a little concerned that you seem to have a lot of experience dealing with crashes. Not sure if I'd highlight that on my resume if I were you :)