# Can you remove username pii from MiniDumpWriteDump?

Tags: windows, winapi, crash-dumps

So when my app crashes it generates a minidump that is uploaded to server for analysis.

These are the type flags currently used: `MiniDumpWithThreadInfo|MiniDumpWithProcessThreadData|MiniDumpWithUnloadedModules`

The minidump contains the exe path (c:\Users{USERNAME}\Appdata...) in the module list.
Is there a way to strip exe path from the minidump to avoid collecting the username pii?

I'm know the modules list is saved as a colon delimited wchar strings inside the dump, I can probably write a few lines of code to search/replace the path from the dump with only the exe name.

I was wondering if there is a known way to exclude this information from being written in the first place or a more elegant way to struct parse the file to remove the info?

Comment: Have you tried `MiniDumpFilterModulePaths` (see [MINIDUMP_TYPE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minidumpapiset/ne-minidumpapiset-minidump_type)).

Comment: The minidump probably also contains the memory backing the process' [environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/environment-variables). Among others, there's `%USERPROFILE%` which contains the same information you're trying to strip. There's probably more data you would have to remove.

Comment: @ssbssa thanks, I missed this option, it did remove the paths from all modules, but also in debugger it was able to load system symbols with no issue (which is great). You can write this as an answer is it does answer my original question.

Comment: @IInspectable now that you mentioned it, I indeed see the env variables in the dump file, I don't see any option to strip those out, I think I'll have to get creative, thanks for pointing this to me

Comment: I believe you can filter memory regions by providing a callback, giving you complete control over which memory gets included and which memory doesn't. I included two links at the bottom of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41433641/1889329) that contain insanely valuable information on how to customize minidumps. Unfortunately, the links are plain `http` (not `https`) and your browser may refuse to follow them. You can use the [wayback machine](https://archive.org/) to read them anyway.

Comment: Cross site almost duplicate: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3874/removing-personal-data-from-dump-file conclusion: It is very hard. This is probably the reason why you would need to sign a data protection policy when you wanted to download crash dumps from Microsoft.